# datetime field in solr schema

Tags: mysql, datetime, solr

I am using Solr to make search on my database, and i need to get a field with (datetime) data type from mysql database, so i set the select query to get this field in dataconfig.xml, and i added field name for this field in schema.xml as follow:

`<field name="parsed_at" type="datetime" indexed="true" stored="true" />`

but solr didn't do any indexing after these modifications.
i have tried to

```
select date(parsed_at) as parsed_at ...
```

and to specify type as date in schema.xml, but this didn't work for unknown reason
does solr support any data type compatible with datatime or timestamp in mysql??

Answer (score 6):

Solr is compatible with typical MySql date formats in an MySQL table, like Y-m-d (and so on)
If parsed_at column in MySQL is from type `datetime`, so you don't need any modifications on select time, as long your field name(solr)=cloumn name(MySQL).

So try `select parsed_at from ...`. Solr will process the date

```
<field name="parsed_at" type="datetime" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Be sure, that an fieldType (type=)`datetime` in Solr's schema.xml exits. If it is so, please post the configuration here. If not, check if, the following line exits in `schema.xml`, which is default:

```
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

Field type `tdate` can handle date-formats.
If you have this field definition in your `schema.xml`, your parsed_at field could use that type:

```
<field name="parsed_at" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

Comment: i have used tdate as you said, it didn't work :( <str name="Total Rows Fetched">17792</str>
<str name="Total Documents Processed">0</str>
  how can i check what is going wrong?? is there a way to enable error log to show such errors??

Comment: edit your question and add: the SQL string you use for the data import handler and the field definition from the schema.xml

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the DataImportHandler? In that case you will need to tell SOLR how the date is stored. You do this using the `DateFormatTransformer`transformer:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource
      type='JdbcDataSource' 
      driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' 
      url='jdbc:mysql://localhost/DATABASE?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull'
      batchSize='-1' 
      user='USER' 
      password='PASS'/>
    <document name='objects'>
        <entity name='object' pk='id' transformer='DateFormatTransformer' query='BLA' >
    <field column='id' />
            <field column='created' dateTimeFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Note that I stuck `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`behind the url. This prevents errors with empty dates.

Comment: ?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL on the JDBC connection string is important with the MySQL JDBC driver. Otherwise Solr can find a null datetime, thinks it's invalid (as a 0 date) and throws an import error. Incidentally this isn't a problem out of the box with the MariaDB driver and caused me a lot of confusion when switching between drivers.