# how to import and index data from database in solr 6.2.1(New to solr)

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, import

I am trying to index data from MySql,bt when execute it from solr admin, it only shows: Request:1, Fetched:0, Skipped:0

New to solr. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your log, from the Solr Admin Panel, if there's any hint about the indexing process, at the url **/solr/#/~logging** if you see any error while trying to importing documents, clicking on the log line will give you additional information about the error.

Since you're mentioning Solr Admin I guess you're using the Data Import Handler.

Here is a very (very!) basic configuration, assuming you're indexing from mysql:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://yourhost:3306/db_name"
    user="mysql_user"
    password="mysql_password"/>
      <document>
      <entity name="mydocuments" 
         query="select id, field1, field2, field3 from yourtable;">

      </entity>
    </document>
  </dataConfig>
```

When running the indexer, check these two checkboxes:

```
Commit: to execute a commit after the import

Auto-Refresh Status: to updated the import stats while it's running
```

Also, check if in your schema is defined a field *version*

```
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thank you for replying. actually what is happening is it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Actually what is happening is it doesn't show any error. Firstly I made a core using command solr create -c wiki3 -> then I got folder wiki3 i my server/solr, I made solrconfig.xml, data-config.xml, schema.xml, after that I go to my browser localhost:8983/solr -> it runs solr, from core selector I selected wiki3, from dataimport menu I clicked on execute.. after it shows Request:1, Skipped:0, Fetched:1.. I don't know what to do now?

Comment: in your mysql table is there a primary key? the host / dbname / user / pwd for the db connection are correct?

Comment: hey my code runs.. actually I did a silly mistake, wrongly spelt my table name.

Comment: now I am including otther field also... for including date and datetime... is solr supports datetime? and what type to choose for date only?

Comment: great! you know.. most of the bugs comes from a mispelled variable ;-) yes, Solr supports datetime, check this answer, and eventually feel free to ask for more information: 
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939383/datetime-field-in-solr-schema

Comment: yes I already checked that. But after executing, it shows indexing complete. Adde/Updated 0 documents. I checked log, in one message it is showing-> unable to read:dataimport. properties  and rest of them reads-> Error creating document: SolrInputDocument.

Comment: could be related to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442884/solr-data-import-properties-doesnt-exist

also, if you click on the exception (in the logs view) can you expand it? is there any stack trace?

Comment: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=23] Error adding field 'num_last_vol_online'='' msg=For input string: ""

Comment: by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""    some of the fields are empty as 'num_last_vol_online', Is the empty field anything to do with these error?

Comment: ok, so I guess that 'num_last_vol_online' should be a number. is it a valid field in your mysql table? is it always valorized? is it correctly selected from your query in the DIH ?

Comment: yes, that's probable. how is it defined in your Solr schema? is it required or not?

Comment: Its a VARCHAR in DB, and I take it as string in schema.xml.... is it creating problem?

Answer (score 0):

this link [quick start](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_2_1/quickstart.html) is a quick guide from apache solr which should help. There are different index samples. A link to the HTTP GUI interface is also mentioned. There you can take a look at the cores (indices) and configurations.

Comment: I am using windows, and I got to know that bin/post -c gettingstarted example/*xml.. -c option doesn't work in windows. Secondally when I tried to use this command ./././bin> java -jar example/exampledocs/post.jar -h, it shows unspecified path as example docs is not in bin.. but to start solr, I have to go to the bin path.